# nil value when there is one

Tags: iphone, swift

Hi guys sorry to bother you again, here is my issue, in the following code execution i am getting the following error:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386 INVOP, subcode =0x0) 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is the code:
[image]
The weird part is that when I do in the output window the following "**po gift!.date.occasion**" ( the exact same line as the code) that returns a value. This is the debugging
[image]

Any ideas what am I doing  wrong?

Comment: Try: po textFieldOccasion to check this for nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that your text field is nil, not the gift variable. Double check that this outlet is connected.

Comment: you were absolutely right, i was checking the wrong side of the line.